# Hyperlink with # (number sign)

Tags: hyperref

I want to add a hyperlink

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\href{http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybridorbital#Beispiele}
     {http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybridorbital#Beispiele}
\end{document}
```

which has a `#` in the link, however if I enter it as `\# Beispiele` it won't open the link in the PDF and only if I leave the section after `#` will it open the page. However, I want it to open at a specific section in the webpage, which is coded by the `#` part.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please note that you can mark inline code with back ticks like `\`code\``. Furthermore I made a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) of your code but adding a documentclass.

Comment: Do you really mean `\\# Beispiele` and not `\# Beispiele` (single backslash)?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have to prefix the hash with a backslash:

```
\href{http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybridorbital#Beispiele}
{http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybridorbital\#Beispiele}
```

Now it should work ;)

Comment: Note that the prefixed backslash is only necessary in the second argument which is the on to be typset by the TeX engin and therefore must respect TeX special symbols (which `#` is one of). The first argument is the verbatim link an though doesn’t need special cares on symbols.

Comment: I got it now! My mistake was that I wrote \# Beispiel instead of \#Beispiel (without space in between) because I thought it wouldn't recognise the second command.

Answer (score 10):

use `\url` instead:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\url{http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybridorbital#Beispiele}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Didn't think of that :)
Note that `\url` typesets the url in typewriter font by default.

Comment: Just use `\urlstyle{same}` to change this behaviour. @Micha may like to add this to the answer.