# Pound sign # in \href link in beamer's frame environment

Tags: beamer, hyperref, symbols, urls

While there's normally no problem with having the pound sign # in an `\href` link (see [Hyperlink with # (number sign)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/106514/hyperlink-with-number-sign)), it does not work within a `frame` environment in `beamer`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\href{http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybridorbital#Beispiele}{Wiki}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

This results in the error `! Illegal parameter number in definition of \iterate.`

Remove the `frame` environment, though, and it compiles fine. So my question is, how can I include an `\href` link with the symbol # in a `frame` environment in `beamer`?

---

EDIT: A comment suggests to add the option `[fragile]` to the `frame` environment. While that takes care of the MWE above, it won't fix the fact the MWE below also crashes because of the pound sign # in the `\href` link:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
\only<1>{\href{http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybridorbital#Beispiele}}{Wiki}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

This gives the error `! Illegal parameter number in definition of \beamer@doifinframe.` Remove the pound sign # from the link, though, and it compiles without error.

Comment: Frames with verbatim content (`\href` is sort of verbatim) require the `fragile` option: `\begin{frame}[fragile]`.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Add `\only<1>{}` to the frame content, and it breaks again, even with `[fragile]`.

Comment: Only if you do `\only<1>{\href{...}}`. As with all verbatim commands, `\href` usually won't work as argument to another command.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik It works without the pound sign #, so it's not the `\href` itself which is the problem here. It's its combination with #.

Comment: without the # it works as \href doesn't have to handle a special char, as soon as you use special chars you can't use \href in the argument of another command. Use an environment instead of \only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`beamer` scans the entire `frame` environment before actually typesetting anything, and this leads to problems with verbatim content, because it cannot be "seen" before it is actually being typeset, or the tokenization will happen too early and it will not work.

Essentially, what happens in your first example is:

```latex
\def\iterate{Hybridorbital#Beispiele}
```

which throws the error:

```
! Illegal parameter number in definition of \iterate.
<to be read again>
                   B
l.4 \def\iterate{Hybridorbital#B
```

The next example shows the same issue, except that the problem doesn't happen while `beamer` is scanning the `frame`, but when it grabs the argument of `\only`. As a rule of thumb, con't use verbatim commands as argument to other commands.

To work around the issue, you can escape the `#`. The documentation of `\href` says:

> [image]

So this works (because `\#` is not the "special" character `#`):

```latex
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\only<1>{\href{http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybridorbital\#Beispiele}{Wiki}}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I thought the escape character ``\`` was only for the text argument, not the url argument, and that putting ``\`` in the url would be interpreted literally. Good to know!

Comment: @Sverre TeX in general is tricky: everything can have a different meaning in a different context. `\href` makes sure that both `#` and `\#` mean the _character_ `#`.

Comment: When I do this, XeLaTeX converts the `\#` to `%23` in the URL, spoiling the hyperlink.

Comment: @jvriesem That's not XeLaTeX or `hyperref`, it's (very, very likely) your PDF viewer: https://github.com/latex3/hyperref/issues/110.  Are you by chance using Preview, Skip, Safari or TeXShop?